# WCF File-less activation needs source code file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I've created a WCF service using File-less activation, I have an interface (IService) and its implementation (Service) in App_code folder (the only way that the service works), I've added the relative address in serviceActivations (web.config), etc. The service works, but if I Publish the service to a folder (IIS) then the App_code folder containing the .cs file (Service) is copied too, so the problem is:
I don't want to have a source file in the publication, if I delete the App_code folder the service crashes.
How Can I avoid that? How Do I have to configure the service? Or this is a 'feature' of File-less activation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to put anything in the App_Code folder. Check the Build Action in the file properties for your source files outside the App_Code folder - should be "Compile". What VS project type are you using? What is the actual exception you get when you delete the App_Code folder?

Comment: thank you, I've checked the Buil Action and Service class was 'Content', I've changed to 'Compile' and _voilá_. Now App_Code folder is not copied.